# Dynamic method return types in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, methods

The following code does exactly what I want it to, but I am curious if there is a better way of going about it. This would be so much easier if Interfaces allowed static methods, or if Java methods could be generalized/parameterized to the extent they can in C#.

I would much rather substitute the parameter "`Class<TParsedClass> c`" for "`Class<AbstractClass> c`". To me "`Class<AbstractClass>`" means a class that extends a certain abstract class, but apparently that is wrong because when I use that parameter and use it as I descibed above, I get compiler errors.

```
public <TData, TParsedClass> TParsedClass convert(TData data, Class<TParsedClass> c)
{
    try 
    {
        return (TParsedClass)c.getMethod("parse", data.getClass()).invoke(c, data);
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw you don't need `TData` to be generic. this will be sufficient: `public <TParsedClass> TParsedClass convert(Object data, Class<TParsedClass> c)`

Comment: You do not need `TData`, you can just use objcet. It should result the same.

Comment: Thanks, I never really thing to use plain old Objects for some reason

Comment: 'substitute the parameter "Class c" for "Class c"' What does that mean?

Comment: forgot to put that part in a <code> block, its fixed now

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a better way. Use interfaces:

```
public interface Parser< TData, TParsedClass >
{
    TParsedClass parse( TData data );
}

public class IntParser
    implements Parser< String, Integer >
{
    public Integer parse( String data )
    {
       return Integer.valueOf( data );
    }
}

public <TData, TParsedData> TParsedData convert(
        TData data,
        Parser< TData, TParsedData > parser
    )
{
    return parser.parse( data );
}
```

Comment: It just seems wasteful to instantiate and pass a new object just to gain access to a method that makes more sense to be static anyway. But, if its more efficient than reflection, I could deal with it, even if it does seem sloppy for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to guess what you "exactly want to do", but I suppose you have some kind of TParsedClass with a static parse method, which populates a new TParsedClass instance with data from a TData instance.

If you think you need some kind of interface marker to indicate which other object a class can parse, why don't you implement the parse method as a non-static method, which populates 'this' with the data from the passed Object?

E.g.

```
public class A implements Parser<B> {
    public void parse(B b) {
        this.foo = b.foo;
        this.bar = b.bar;
    }
 }
```

To convert, you would then do something like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.parse(b);
```

instead of

```
A a = A.parse(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define TParsedClass as TParsedClass extends AbstractClass, but the Class object doesn't represent an abstract class, it is a way of referring to the definition of a type via reflection.